# Convert complex type of string array to json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have string of an array like the following:

```
  let temparr = ['01.10.2019    1570950138      Accounts Receivable     21000  ',
                       '                        Retailer Opening                        21000 '];
```

I would like to convert this array like the following json file

```
const convertedObjectdata = {
            'Date': 01.10.2019,
            'VoucherNo': 1570950138,
            'chartOfAccount: [Accounts Receivable,Retailer Opening]
            'CreditAmount': [21000],
            'DebitAmount': [21000]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Split by a sequence of two or more spaces using a regular expression:

```js
const str = 'Date           Voucher No.     Chart of Accounts       Debit Tk.      Credit Tk.'

const result = str.split(/\s{2,}/)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on a space regex

```
str.split(/\s+/);
```